# Pass parameters to router's controller method

Tags: php, laravel

It was kind of hard for me to form this as a title. Basically what I have is a simple laravel-like router that saves allowed locations in an array. My question is if I could supply some arguements dynamically through that array's elements. I think I did even worse in the body of the question so let me just give a simple example:

```
class Example(){
    public function display($bool){
        if($bool){
            echo 'hey';
        }else{
            echo 'bye';
        }
    }
}
```

Now if you wanna call this class' method from somewhere else with a variable

```
$var = 'display';
$example = new Example();
$example->$var(true);
```

And you get 'hey', but what if I can only control the `$var = 'display'` part, and the code below is beyond my control. Can I still pass a value to that method? Something like

```
$var = 'display(true)';
$example = new Example();
$example->$var;
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not without some epic string parsing.

More importantly, if you need this, something that you're doing is **horribly** wrong.

Comment: I don't actually **need** it, I was just wondering if I could add it as a functionality. Apparently I'll go without it `:D`, Thanks!

Comment: @php_nub_qq: I'm still very interested in knowing how you got to that situation. Care to drop in the [PHP room](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/11/php) and chat?